# addEventListener exclusions

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

So I made a site and I add an addEventListener on click but the site has 2 buttons and Id like it to work on only 1.

```
// Installing handler on click
document.querySelector('.my-open-trigger').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  // Open authorization
  sa.open()
}, false)
```

Id like the auth window to open only when the right button is clicked. If not the normal action from the HTTML code should execute.

Comment: both buttons have the same class? Provide the html code

Comment: `document.querySelector('.my-open-trigger')` will select the first element with `class="my-open-trigger"` and ignore any others. To select the second element, you need `document.querySelectorAll('.my-open-trigger')[1]`. Better use an id though.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the event using the button id instead of ones that contain a class

```
<div id="DivId">
THIS WILL RUN IT
</div>

document.getElementById("DivId").addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  // Open authorization
  sa.open()
}, false)
```

Comment: You need to define what sa.Open is. When i tried this it did run but i assumed that you had already set up sa.open(); Also there should be a ';' after preventDefault and sa.open(). Press F12 and it will show you the error under the console.